# Django reverse going for the wrong view function

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I have the following url patterns defined in the `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('start', views.start, name='start'),
    path('<slug:id>' , views.person, name="person"),
    path('family/<slug:id>', views.family, name="family")
]
```

And the first 3 works just fine, for example if I call this link:

```
<a href="{% url 'pops:person' id=my_id %}">
```

Everything works fine and I go to the persons page, The other link such as start and index also works fine.

But somehow if I do this link:

```
<a href="{% url 'pops:family' id=my_id %}">
```

Everything fails and throws a reverse not found error:

```
Reverse for 'index' with keyword arguments '{'id': 'BLAHBLAH'}' not found.
```

The problem is, I'm not even going for the `index`, Why is it reversing for `index` when it should be reversing for `family`? As a result, it's not even hitting the function defined in the views at all.

Comment: Fixed issue by moving to 'family' and turning id to a get request and moving that path to the front of url list, still don't quite understand this behavior

Comment: Your `id` is str, not int?

Comment: Just check your link in the template with my_id is it according to your model? If you are adding slug, don't add it in the beginning, e.g. path(something/<slug:..>) or keep `path('<slug:id>' , views.person, name="person"),` at the end.